# Android Studio Bumblebee not working with gpg

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gnupg

I have gpg configured and working in my system, but after updating to Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1, every time I try to commit something it shows an error:

```
Commit failed with error
0 file committed, 1 file failed to commit: Change api to 30
cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
gpg failed to sign the data
failed to write commit object
```

From terminal I'm able to commit (with gpg working), even with Android Studio's terminal. I installed Android Studio Arctic Fox on a separated folder and it's still working with gpg.

```
macOS Big Sur 11.6.1
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be related to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216364005 where Android Studio can't source the environment variables.

Opening AS through command line should solve it until there is a new version available: `open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`